# Does Apollo cache.readQuery return a copy?

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-client

I was going through the [mutation doc](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/mutations.html#update), and was wondering if `cache.readQuery` returns a copy?

For instance:

```
const { todos } = cache.readQuery({ query: GET_TODOS });

// Should I copy it first or is it already copied?
// todos = Object.assign({}, todos)

todos.items.concat([addTodo])
cache.writeQuery({
          query: GET_TODOS,
          data: { todos: todos }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`readQuery` doesn't return a copy**

you can test this now by reading then mutating then reading the query again to see if the results have changed

```
const { todos } = cache.readQuery({ query: GET_TODOS });

todos[0].completed = null;

const data.todos = cache.readQuery({ query: GET_TODOS });

console.log(data.todos[0].completed) // true or false
```

**Source code**

If we look at the source code we can see the readQuery boils down to this function graphqlAnywhere

```
 const result = graphqlAnywhere(
    readStoreResolver,
    query,
    rootIdValue,
    context,
    variables,
    {
      fragmentMatcher: fragmentMatcherFunction,
      resultMapper,
    },
  );

  return {
    result,
    complete: !context.hasMissingField,
  };
```

Each graphqlAnywhere function starts with a new object there is no direct reference to the cache store so you don't need to worry about making a copy before mutating.

> https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/master/packages/graphql-anywhere/src/graphql.ts
>
> https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/91f5116ce830151e6bedf92e10550c607984e11c/packages/apollo-cache-inmemory/src/readFromStore.ts#L175